# Android ListView with custom adapter aligning specific rows

Tags: android, xml, listview

I am already familiar with the basics and am pretty close to what I want to achieve. I want to have two different layouts in total for the rows but don't want it to be a set pattern of alternation. There could be any pattern for the two row layouts.

My question is how do I use two different xml layouts depending on the information that is going to be displayed? Or if possible, use a single layout and work with visibility for simplicity (current implementation).

Is it possible to send another parameter into `getViewItemType()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can set another parameter into getItemViewType (int position) as it only takes one parameter and returns the view that is created by getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) on a specific item.
I wolud recommend you using the setVisibility() on a specofic xml Layout which you don't want to display.
Or you can just maintain a small SQliteDatabase for storing what all the items you want to make it visible and call the adapter according to that value in the database.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In android adapter any time you can call "getItem()" and with help of that you can decide which layout to show.

Don't forget to override getItem() in your adapter class.

Comment: This works well too, but I was closer to finishing the method used by the other answer than this one. Thanks though :)